How do I display the current time in a different timezone?
I've done a clock in Python, but I have one problem. The timezone is set at UTC, but I want to change it to time in Warsaw. Can you help me?
from tkinter import *
from time import *


def update():


    time_string = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time_label.config(text=time_string)
    
    day_string = strftime("%A")
    day_label.config(text=day_string)

    date_string = strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    date_label.config(text=date_string)
    
    window.after(1000,update)

window = Tk()

time_label = Label(window,font=("Arial",50),fg="#0000ff",bg="white")
time_label.pack()

day_label = Label(window,font=("Comic sans",25,"bold"))
day_label.pack()

date_label = Label(window,font=("Comic Sans MS",30))
date_label.pack()

update()

window.mainloop()



Use pytz library.

Perhaps this post could help.

Here is the code using pytz.
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from datetime import datetime
import pytz


def update():
    utc_timezone = pytz.utc
    utc_time = datetime.now(utc_timezone)

    # Define Warsaw timezone
    warsaw_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')

    # Convert UTC time to Warsaw time
    warsaw_time = utc_time.astimezone(warsaw_timezone)

    time_string = warsaw_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time_label.config(text=time_string)
    
    day_string = strftime("%A")
    day_label.config(text=day_string)

    date_string = strftime("%B %d, %Y")
    date_label.config(text=date_string)
    
    window.after(1000,update)

window = Tk()

time_label = Label(window,font=("Arial",50),fg="#0000ff",bg="white")
time_label.pack()

day_label = Label(window,font=("Comic sans",25,"bold"))
day_label.pack()

date_label = Label(window,font=("Comic Sans MS",30))
date_label.pack()

update()

window.mainloop()


That's not the output, that's the code.

You can simply call warsaw_time = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Warsaw')) and then use warsaw_time to update the labels. Note that you should use warsaw_time.strftime(...) for day_string and date_string.
